# Does SVM always converge?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I am using scikit-learn in python to classify my instances using svm.SVC; however, for some combination of parameters fitting never stops. Is this because the algorithm needs more time. Or is it possible that algorithm does not converge to an extremum point.

Note that I am not making any assumption about my data. Knowing that, does svm always converge for arbitrary datasets?

Comment: You can change `max_iter` if it takes too much time. `max_iter=-1` will allow it to turn indefinitly

Comment: ```In theory libsvm guarantees to converge. Therefore, this means you are handling ill-conditioned situations (e.g. too large/small parameters) so numerical difficulties occur.``` [from libsvm faq here (core-algorithm of SVC)](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html). Your behaviour is common as some params tend to use more support-vectors which will have some effect in regards to performance! Also: the optimization itself is using heuristics to speed up convergence which sometimes will work well, sometimes not (again: params).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should always converge, unless there are numerical problems.

Make sure your data is properly scaled. It is a bad idea if different features have values in different orders of magnitude. You might want to normalize all features to the range [-1,+1], especially for problems with more than 100 features.

> Q: The program keeps running (with output, i.e. many dots). What
> should I do?
>
> In theory libsvm guarantees to converge. Therefore, this
> means you are handling ill-conditioned situations (e.g. too
> large/small parameters) so numerical difficulties occur.
>
> Reference: [https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/libsvm/faq.html)

Comment: Just for completeness, it is usually considered standard to *normalize* (*standarize*) features to `mean = 0 & std = 1` as `feature = (feature - mean(feature)) / std(feature)`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above by Imanol & Others, scale your training and test input.

General standard followed such as: mean=0 and STD=1

You can use StandardScaler API available in sklearn.preprocessing library.

Note: Fit StandardScaler function over training input set only and transform both training and test, so same scale applied.

```
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(train_ip)
scaler.transform(train_ip)
scaler.transform(test_ip)
```